# Reusing 'expensive' UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, avplayerviewcontroller

I am embedding an AVPlayerViewController(which is expensive in terms of resources) in a UIViewController (using containment). I need to use another AVPlayerViewController in the subsequently pushed view controller in navigation stack, but it would be nice if I can remove it from the parent & embed it in the child. When the child pops, I want to embed it back in the parent. What is the elegant way to do this (code or storyboards)?

Comment: It sounds like you are pre-optimising. Create a new one

Comment: I had tried it before. Having multiple AVPlayers in a stack along with AVCaptureSession in the root view controller is a perfect recipe for crashes and hangs. Had too many of them in the past.

Comment: So release the old one before you create a new one.  If you do want to do it, however, you can refer to the *Implementing a Container View Controller* section of [UIViewController documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller); You will need to call `addChild` and `removeFromParent` as appropriate

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it in code. Create your 'expensive' view controller and store it using strong reference somewhere. You can show it programmatically anywhere, then you can dismiss it, but it will be store by strong reference. Later you can show it again.

P.S. looks like you view controller have AVPlayer, in this case probably you need to add some method to 'wipe' its state before reuse or at leave pause playback

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like this way. You need to setup player .

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
class AVViewController: UIViewController {
static var   player : AVPlayerViewController?
@IBOutlet  var containerView: UIView!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.addChildViewController(AVViewController.player!)
    self.containerView.addSubview((AVViewController.player?.view)!)
// setup player here.
    }
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    for vc in self.childViewControllers{
        if let vc =  vc as? AVPlayerViewController, AVViewController.player == nil {
          AVViewController.player = vc
        }
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: That won't reuse the existing instance. The second "main"will fire its own embed segue and embed a new instance of the AVPlayerVC. You can't do what the OP wants with storyboards alone.